# Rails 2 merging conditions for scope in model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two scopes

```
named_scope :by_foo, lambda { |foo| { :conditions =>  {:foo => foo} } }
named_scope :by_bar, lambda { |bar| { :conditions =>  ["bar like ?", bar+"%"] } }
```

How I can mix them together in one scope without chaining ?

```
named_scope :by_baz # what that should look like ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`named_scope :by_baz, lambda {|args| by_foo(args[:foo]).by_bar(args[:bar])}`

You could call it by:

`Model.by_baz({:foo=>value, :bar=>value})`

This way you could add as much scopes as you like without rewriting the condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
named_scope :by_foo_and_bar, lambda { |foo, bar| { :conditions =>  ["foo = ? AND bar like ?", foo, bar+"%"] } }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this implicts code duplication, when You change one of the input scopes, you need to rewrite this too